# SET value in SQL using LEN function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to set @Type = '0' if (LEN(@Token) < 65. How do I do that?

Comment: Aside: From the documentation for [`Len()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql): "Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, **excluding trailing blanks**."

Answer (score 3):

Remove the outer parentheses.

`IF LEN(@Token) < 65 SET @Type = '0'`;

Example:

```
DECLARE @token VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @Type VARCHAR(100) = '1';

SET @token = 'asdfasdfaf';

IF LEN(@Token) < 65 SET @Type = '0';

PRINT @Type;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!